# Link the CSS file to the HTML one in CGI programm

Tags: html, css, c, apache, cgi

So, I recently started to code a web interface with CGI, after finding how to print hello world on my Apache web page with HTML, I wanted to add some CSS to it but apparently it doesn't work.

I'm on Linux, and I am working with Apache2.

So there is my source file hello.c (which is in /usr/lib/cgi-bin):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf(
        "Context-type:text/html\n\n"
        "<html>\n"
        "<head>\n"
        "<title> Hi world </title>\n"
        "<link type=\"text/css\" rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"style/style.css\">\n"
        "</head>\n"
        "<body>\n"
        "<h2>Hello world !</h2>\n"
        "</body>\n"
        "</html>\n"
    );

    return 0;
}
```

and there is my CSS file (which is in /usr/lib/cgi-bin/style/):

```css
body {
    background-color:rgb(255, 0, 170); 
}

h2 {
    font-family: Times;
    font-size: 38pt;
}
```

I already tried to put my CSS file in my home directory but it doesn't work too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check your network panel of your [browser's debugger](https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/devtools-user/network_monitor/), you're probably encountering a `500` status, as the server refuses to serve `/cgi-bin/style/style.css`.

Generally, style sheets do not belong in the CGI directory. You should move them to somewhere in your `DocumentRoot` path.

---

Assuming your configuration is something like:

```
DocumentRoot "/var/www"
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/usr/lib/cgi-bin/"
```

Set your directory structure to:

```
/usr/lib/
└── cgi-bin
    └── hello.cgi
/var/www
└── style
    └── style.css
```

Then change the relative path

```
"<link type=\"text/css\" rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"style/style.css\">\n"
```

to an absolute path (note the `/` prefix):

```
"<link type=\"text/css\" rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"/style/style.css\">\n"
```

Comment: It works !! thank you! I did what you said I moved my directory style in the DocumentRoot which in my case is /var/www/html and I changed to an absolute path for the link and it worked.